# Why some scripts won't work if I place it at the end of <body> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was using moment.js in order to play with dateTime string but when I loaded that on my html file at the end of body tag like other scripts (which worked) it did not work however, I place it in the head tag it strangely worked. My question is why some scripts do not work if I place it at the end of the body tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding the script to the end of body tag is totally fine in general. What do you mean by "some script do not work"? Do you have some errors in console or an example of broken functionality?

Comment: Specifically moment.js does not work when I add it at the end of body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script have to be executed on page ready. If it is in `<head>` part, then the script is executed before any content is rendere to the user, but if is before `<body>` closing tag, it is excuted at the end. You must execute it when the page is fully loaded.

I see you tagged the question with jQuery, here is how you to execute the script when the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    //When everything is ready, execute this code
    alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: even if I do that it still did not work (it is moment.js that caused this problem). I cannot figure out why it is the case. Maybe that is because I wrote javascript inside the html tag instead of separating my script in js (those javascript code that is external to this HTML file works fine even if I place javascript files at the end of the body tag [obviously those code do not use moment.js)

Answer (score 0):

**It won't validate outside of the  or  tags. It also won't make much difference — unless you're doing DOM manipulations that could break IE before the body element is fully loaded — to putting it just before the closing**